# How to execute a sql file in Docker Oracle 12?

Tags: oracle, docker, dockerfile, oracle12c

How can I **execute a sql file** in Docker Oracle 12c [(here is the link of the image)](https://store.docker.com/images/oracle-database-enterprise-edition)
, where is the `/u0p/app/oracle/scripts` or how can I set the permits to docker/oracle to execute this file? 
[I'm in Debian]

I tried to look for the `cd /home/oracle` but I can't find this as root user.

Any idea?

Comment: Do you want to run a script within the docker container? Then run `docker exec -it YourContainerNameHere bash` to get an interactive prompt. This image runs as user `oracle` not as `root`. Environment variables such as $ORACLE_HOME are set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this link to install an Oracle 12c Docker image. I installed it on my Mac.

https://dzone.com/articles/creating-an-oracle-database-docker-image

Download the [**Oracle Instant Client**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/instant-client/downloads/index.html) which includes SQL* Plus.

OR

Download the latest command line tool [**SQLcl**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html)

Now, to run a script you may Connect to your database using the easy connect with sqlplus or sql commandline.

```
sqlplus user/pwd@//localhost:1521/ORCLPDB1 yourpath/yourscript.sql
```

Comment: does it need to be a script or it is possible to pass  SQL query too?